# Extract UITable data to Excel sheet

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-uitable

I am trying to extract data from a `uitable` I have created and export it into an Excel sheet with the Column Headers along with it. By it keeps throwing an **error**, stating:

**Stacktrace:**

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in FatherSonGUI>generateWAR (line 124)
    num = [col';data]

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in FatherSonGUI (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in @(hObject,eventdata)FatherSonGUI('generateWAR',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

**Example Picture:**
[image]

**Here's a sample of my Code that I have written:**

```
dat = dyn_conformer.Data;
set(f,'name','Title','numbertitle','off') %renames the Title Figure
cnames = {'Task Mnemonic','Success Status','External Update Required', 'Correlation ID', 'Event Name','External System','Tech Exception Status','Returned Status','Return Cancel','Return Customer','Return Technical'};
rnames = {'1','2','3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20','21', '22', '23', '24', '25'};
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[10 100 1150 370]); % size of the values inside the figure object

    col = get(t,'ColumnName')
    data = get(t,'Data')
    num = [col';data]
    xlswrite('show.xls',num)
```

The data is being compiled from a database, with simple data within the fields. If I were to remove the `col'` element from the `num` variable, it exports only the data. However, I would like to **export the column names and the data together**, where in the end it will look like a proper spreadsheet.

I would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace that accompanies the error message and a [functional example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better answer your question.

Comment: @excaza Stacktrace and example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error is telling you, the dimensions of your 'col' and 'data' arrays are not consistent. Based on the sample image, the number of columns in your data is greater than the length of your header array. You either need to define all of your headers or trim your data array to the number of defined columns.

The latter:

```
num = [col';data(:,1:length(col))];
```

Though this will trim them in a non-specific manner.

Comment: You're right, it was inconsistent. Furthermore, somehow it shifted my data to another column due to the fact that some of the column had `null` values. Is there a way I could write a statement for it to include all data types regardless if it's null or not null?